# Some error in PHP function output I cannot understand

Tags: php, function

Have a 'function use' lesson problem. The code inside the function (when it's put outside the function; returns an array) seems correct, but the function outputs NULL. Here's what it looks. Point where I'm doing wrong, please.

```
function getDivisors($num)
       {
         for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++)
           {
             if ($num % $i == 0)
               {
                 $divisors[] = $i;
               }
           }
        }
```

I suppose the output to the array is an incorrect, but... that's still unsure.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to `return` the array from the function

Comment: P.s. show us how you're calling the function, for context

Comment: Thank you very much!
The function is a part of an exercise, which demands the use of it in function getCommonDivisors($num1,$num2) like this:
$result[] = array_intersect(getDivisors($num1), getDivisors($num2));
So the whole thing breaks out with NULL as the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns **null** because you didn't return your array.

Modify your function like this :

```
function getDivisors($num) {
  for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
     if ($num % $i == 0) {
        $divisors[] = $i;
     }
  }
  return $divisors;
}
```

Comment: My great thanks. The topic appeared to have lots of pitfalls for me.